# Tor and RTP communication

Tags: tor

Does anyone know if it is real to have VoIP communication over TOR? Is this possible in means that call voice can be delayed about 150 ms?

Can this be somehow solved in TOR clients?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VoIP over Tor is real. Delay is 1-3 sec, and it is required Push-To-Talk mode.
VoIP over Tor solved in my Torfone (see torfone.org) or can be released using Mumble voice chat.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you could find a reliable gateway. A sound connections needs so 8kbyte/sec or so, this isn't really big. The reliability and the packet delay are much more problems.

Skype works through tor, but needs special settings, because it will give your *original* data to the microsoft.

Comment: I got my own SIP gateway - Open Sourced software and I got Jitsio Open Source client - so in ideal it can be setuped to work together through tor?